# AndroidJava_How can I change stings.xml values in androidJava?

Tags: java, android

I want to change FrameLayout's height in scr/MainActivity.java.

dimen.xml:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="FrameLayout_size">100dp</dimen>
```

May I set FrameLayout_size in scr/MainActivity.java?

Comment: When it's a `dimen` you change that file, not the `strings.xml` file

Comment: float a = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.SIZE);

Comment: What does that mean? You are trying to get a dimension. What happens?

Comment: Can you change what?

Comment: Dimension value.My activity_main.xml need to get the dimension value. Can Java change the Dimension value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way still work.

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Frame01);
    LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
    int i = 100;
    params.height = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit the value of a string resource, edit src/main/res/values/strings.xml, to edit a dimension resource, edit dimensions.xml in that same folder.

Comment: How can I get that dimension value and change it?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new dimension value, try creating a new line in the `dimens.xml` file under the `values` folder, that looks like:

```
<dimen name="newDimensionName"> value </dimen>
```

Comment: I create a new line in the dimens.xml.  How can I get that dimension value and change it?

Comment: To get the value of the new dimension use `R.dimen.newDimensionName`. All the data stored in the xml files cannot be modified during runtime. If you want to modify a `String` type value during runtime you could use regular variables.

Comment: But my activity_main.xml need to get the dimension value.

Comment: If you want to use the value in a xml file use the following: `android:xxxx="@dimen/newDimensionName"`.

Comment: float a = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.newDimensionName);